# Cambiar estructura de un json serializado

Tags: c#, json, .net

Estoy trabajando con consumos de diferentes json que tengo en una base de datos, dentro de estos consumos la idea es generar un método en el que al buscar un valor de encabezado json me dé el valor referente a él, obteniendo el json de la base de datos. no tener problemas

Pero al realizar la búsqueda usando el valor del encabezado me toma como valor nulo, adjunto el método donde obtengo el json de la base de datos

```
public string buscarJson()
        {
            String resul = "";
            try
            {
                String query = "select json_appconfig from tbl_config_json where codigo_proyecto='" + codigo_proyecto + "' and esta_proyecto='" + ambiente + "';";
                SqlCommand mc = new SqlCommand(query, establecerConexion());
                SqlDataReader dr;
                dr = mc.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    resul = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dr[0]);
                }
                cerrarConexion();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            return resul;
        }
```

En este método como dije entro a la base de datos y consulto el campo donde está el json, lo contengo en una variable y lo devuelvo, el retorno me da este resultado

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwgZP.png

y al consultar la cabecera que quiero del json utilizo este metodo

```
public string getAppSetting(string valor)
        {
            //string json1 = 
``
("[{\"user\":\"kankor\",\"correo\":\"alpha@e.com\",\"clave\":\"123456\",\"numero\":\"+1 8XX-307-7455\"}]")
``;
            String json1 = buscarJson();
            dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json1);
            var numero = jsonObj[0][valor].ToString();
            return numero;
        }
```

Al contener el método buscarJson en la variable Json y realizar la búsqueda del parámetro que quiero, resulta ser nulo, y lo raro es que al llamar al método en un MessageBox me devuelve el json como lo ingresé en la base.

Dentro del método getAppSetting al cambiar el valor de json1 por un json escrito de esta forma
`("[{\"user\":\"kankor\",\"correo\":\"alpha@e.com\",\"clave\":\"123456\",\"numero\":\"+1 8XX-307-7455\"}]")`

El método funciona perfectamente, así que estoy buscando una opción para modificar el json que obtengo de la base de datos y modificarlo a este formulario.

Psdt: encontré este método getAppSetting aquí https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wgmqpd

Comment: Elimina el `Try/Catch` para que veas si salta un error en tu primera función

Comment: me funciono muchas gracias, algun error sin sentido estuvo separando el resultado deseado

Comment: Buena!!! Yo los try/catch los coloco luego de haber probado todo, porque de lo contrario muchas veces ni te enterar que hay un error